# Find nearest match of objects in JavaScript array

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, sorting, object

I have an array of non-sorted objects:

```
const participants = [
    {code: '222222', is_winner: true},
    {code: '444444', is_winner: false},
    {code: '777777', is_winner: false},
    {code: '555555', is_winner: true},
    {code: '666666', is_winner: false},
    {code: '111111', is_winner: false},
    {code: '333333', is_winner: false},
];
```

How do I find the nearest object, which is_winner key is true, **given** a participant, which is_winner key is always false.

```
if participant = {code: '333333', is_winner: false} 
=> 
Should return {code: '555555', is_winner: true}

if participant = {code: '444444', is_winner: false} 
=> 
Should return {code: '222222', is_winner: true}
```

I'm looking to get a participant that has won(is_winner is true) that is the closest to a non-winner participant. The array is noncircular.

Comment: 222222 is nearer to 333333. Your logic doesn’t make sense

Comment: @chrispbacon I see what you mean. I'm looking to find just adjacent participants, and not loop over the array again. In that case, you are correct, 222222 is closer to 333333 than 555555.

Comment: @chrispbacon why do you assume the array is circular? I dont think thats a fair assumption to make.

Comment: Your question is super unclear. Can you edit it to reflect what you would like to happen, any constraints (like the one in the above comment), and the expected outcome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my answer from the information in your question

```js
const participants = [
    {code: '222222', is_winner: true},
    {code: '444444', is_winner: false},
    {code: '777777', is_winner: false},
    {code: '555555', is_winner: true},
    {code: '666666', is_winner: false},
    {code: '111111', is_winner: false},
    {code: '333333', is_winner: false},
];

function findClosestWinner(code, participants) {
    let index = participants.findIndex((participant) => {
        return participant.code === code
    })
    let winner
    let awayDown = 0
    let awayUp = 0
    for (let x = index-1; x >= 0; x--) {
        let currentParticipant = participants[x]
        awayDown += 1
        if (currentParticipant.is_winner) {
            winner = currentParticipant
            break
        }
    }
    for (let x = index+1; x < participants.length; x++) {
        let currentParticipant = participants[x]
        awayUp += 1
        if (currentParticipant.is_winner && awayUp <= awayDown) {
            winner = currentParticipant
            break
        }
    }
    return winner
}
let winner = findClosestWinner('777777', participants)
console.log(winner)
```

`findClosestWinner` takes a participant's code and the list of participants and returns the closest winning participant.

hopefully, this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in one loop. Added comments but the principal is simple, loop through while watching out for a winner and storing it until you find the matching code. Once you found the code you are searching for find an upper winner. If found then find the closest one.

There might be some edge cases around the match being a winner, but since you didn't address those in your example problems I am going to pretend like they don't exist and let you program for them ;)

```js
let findCloseWinner = (code, participants) => {
    var low=-1, codeIx=-1;
    for(var i=0;i<participants.length;i++) {
        if(participants[i].code === code) codeIx = i;
        if(participants[i].is_winner) {
            // if we havent found our code then we have a new lower bound
            if(codeIx === -1) {
                low = i;
            } else {
                // find closer, is it lower or upper
                if(low === -1 || codeIx-low > i-codeIx) {
                    return participants[i];
                } else {
                    return participants[low];
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // If no code was found or we never found a lower bound then were done
    if(codeIx === -1 || low === -1) return null
    // no upper bound found during loop, low must be winner
    return participants[low];
}

var participants = [
    {code: '222222', is_winner: true},
    {code: '444444', is_winner: false},
    {code: '777777', is_winner: false},
    {code: '555555', is_winner: true},
    {code: '666666', is_winner: false},
    {code: '111111', is_winner: false},
    {code: '333333', is_winner: false},
];

console.log(findCloseWinner('333333', participants));
console.log(findCloseWinner('444444', participants));
```

Answer (score 1):

This can simply be:

```js
const data = [ {code: '222222', is_winner: true}, {code: '444444', is_winner: false}, {code: '777777', is_winner: false}, {code: '555555', is_winner: true}, {code: '666666', is_winner: false}, {code: '111111', is_winner: false}, {code: '333333', is_winner: false}, ];

let fn = (c, arr) => {
  let i = arr.findIndex(x => x.code === c)
  return data.slice(0, i).reverse().find(x => x.is_winner)
}

console.log(fn('333333', data))  // 555555
console.log(fn('444444', data))  // 222222
```

The idea is to get the `index` of the item with the provided `code` after which to slice the main array so you only have the items up to that index. Then simply reverse the result and get the first match on `is_winner`.